# sorting listviewitems in different groups in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, sorting, collections

need a small logical help:
I have a collection of listview item which needs to be categorized in different groups according to its category(listviewitem.tag.tostring())
forexample: I have 10 items in a listview with thier tags 'food' 'vegetables' 'drinks' etc. now I want the items  in a collection with these tags.

thanks in advance

Comment: You want to group them into **collections**? Or you want to group them visually (so that you can see each group in the `ListView`)?

Comment: It is not very polite to post an unclear question, without any example code, without showing what you tried, without indicating where you ran into a problem *especially* if you then disappear for hours so people asking for clarification do not get any answers.

Comment: there is no code to share. I just need the logical help. I still couldn't figure out from where should I begin. @KingKing,yes I want to group the in collections it doesnt need to be visually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<string,List<ListViewItem>>` to store the groups, the `Key` is the group key which can be `food`, `vegetables`, `drinks`, ... (category names). The `Value` is the list of items in the corresponding category.

```
var groups = listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>()
                      .GroupBy(e=>e.Tag.ToString())
                      .ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, v=>v.ToList());
//Then to access a category's items, just pass in the category name into the Dictionary like this
var food = groups["food"];//this is a List<ListViewItem> of items in the category 'food'
//try printing the items
foreach(var f in food)
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(f.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Life with a ListView is MUCH simpler if you use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) -- an open source wrapper around a standard .NET ListView.

For example, enabling grouping is a one line, which tells the control which group each row belongs to:

```
lastPlayedColumn.GroupKeyGetter = delegate(object rowObject) { 
    Song song = (Song)rowObject; 
    return new DateTime(song.LastPlayed.Year, song.LastPlayed.Month, 1); 
};
```

Which gives this:

[image: ObjectListView with groups]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/gettingstarted-example52.png))</sub>

With only a little bit more work, you can create something fancy like this:

[image: ObjectListView with fancy groups]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/_images/group-formatting.png))</sub>